# Pycharm Pipenv with extra index, define by environment variable

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pipenv

I'm unable to get Pycharm (2020.x, and fresh 2021 version) to "Add interpreter", as "Pipenv environment", because some environment variable are not defined => it is clear for me it is because they are GNU/Bash environment variables.

To be clear, the Pipfile contains this (simplified here) definition:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://'${EXTRA_INDEX_CREDENTIALS}'@host/path/to/extra/pypi/index"
verify_ssl = true
name = "my_extra_index"
```

How is it possible to configure **Pycharm itself**, to know how to substitude the `$EXTRA_INDEX_CREDENTIALS` variable, and be able to setup such Pipenv interpreter?